# My first login attempt it doesnt give me any message

Tags: java, android, forms, authentication, http-post

The first attempt to login, whether the login info is correct or not, i get no response back, when its supposed to say either "Incorrect User ID / Password" or "Login Successful! ". But any time after the first attempt it prints the correct message, why is it doing this?

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_un);
    pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
//  error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_error);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /**
             * According with the new StrictGuard policy, running long tasks
             * on the Main UI thread is not possible So creating new thread
             * to create and execute http operations
             */
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID",
                            un.getText().toString()));
                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",
                            pw.getText().toString()));

                    String response = null;
                    try {
                        response = SimpleHttpClient
                                .executeHttpPost("website",
                                        postParameters);
                         res = response.toString();

                        resp = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                        System.out.println(res);


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        errorMsg = e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                /**
                 * Inside the new thread we cannot update the main thread So
                 * updating the main thread outside the new thread
                 */

                //error.setText(resp);
                if(res.indexOf("<TITLE>LoginOk</TITLE>") != -1  ||(resp.indexOf("<TITLE>Login</TITLE>") != -1)) {                   
                    textview.setText("Incorrect User ID / Password");


                }
                else if(res.indexOf("Already") != -1){

                textview.setText("An account is already logged In");
                }
                else{
                textview.setText("Login Successful! ");
                }
                if (null != errorMsg && !errorMsg.isEmpty()) {
                    textview.setText(errorMsg);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                textview.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is getting the response from server a bit late. Why don't you use `AsyncTask`? You can update your textview in `onPostExecute()`. Then you don't be having this problem.

Comment: Can you help me out a bit on how i would implement AsyncTask in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_un);
    pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             String username = un.getText().toString()));
             String password = pw.getText().toString()));
              new MyTask().execute(username, password);   // here I'm sending these two values to AsyncTask class
           }
    });

}

// here is the AsyncTask

    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


       ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID",
                            params[0]));    // params[0] contains the first value that you have passed and params[1] second value.
                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",
                            params[1]));

                    String response = null;
                    try {
                        response = SimpleHttpClient
                                .executeHttpPost("http://www.e-learning.com/wlc_loginok.asp",
                                        postParameters);
                         res = response.toString();

                        resp = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                        System.out.println(res);

                         return res;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        errorMsg = e.getMessage();
                    }
   }  // end of doInBackground

      @Override
    protected Void onPostExecute(String res){
        super.onPostExecute(res);
        if(res.indexOf("<TITLE>LoginOk</TITLE>") != -1  ||(resp.indexOf("<TITLE>Login</TITLE>") != -1)) {                   
                    textview.setText("Incorrect User ID / Password");


                }
                else if(res.indexOf("Already") != -1){

                textview.setText("An account is already logged In");
                }
                else{
                textview.setText("Login Successful! ");
                }
                if (null != errorMsg && !errorMsg.isEmpty()) {
                    textview.setText(errorMsg);
                }
    }  // end of onPostExecute
}  // end of AsyncTask class
```

Comment: Perfect! only error was that i think its supposed to be  protected String doInBackground instead of void, because it gave me an error otherwise. anyways thanks!

Comment: Please up vote it too, so that it will be useful for others facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, conditions which you put to display message, execute before your thread run so your response alway null or blank which does not satisfy any of your condition and because of this, not execute correctly.

What you need to do is, simply implement handler which you need to call in thread, after your main code implementation.

```
                final Handler handler = new Handler(){

                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    super.handleMessage(msg);

                      /**
                     * Inside the new thread we cannot update the main thread So
                     * updating the main thread outside the new thread
                     */

                    //error.setText(resp);
                    if(res.indexOf("<TITLE>LoginOk</TITLE>") != -1  ||(resp.indexOf("<TITLE>Login</TITLE>") != -1)) {                   
                        textview.setText("Incorrect User ID / Password");


                    }
                    else if(res.indexOf("Already") != -1){

                    textview.setText("An account is already logged In");
                    }
                    else{
                    textview.setText("Login Successful! ");
                    }
                    if (null != errorMsg && !errorMsg.isEmpty()) {
                        textview.setText(errorMsg);
                    }
                }

            };


            Thread thread = new Thread(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    super.run();


                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID",
                            un.getText().toString()));
                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",
                            pw.getText().toString()));

                    String response = null;
                    try {
                        response = SimpleHttpClient
                                .executeHttpPost("http://www.e-learning.com/wlc_loginok.asp",
                                        postParameters);
                         res = response.toString();

                        resp = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                        System.out.println(res);


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        errorMsg = e.getMessage();
                    }finally{
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }

                }

            };
            thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get response lik this and process further.

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity rp = response.getEntity();

//String builder from response
if (rp.getContentLength() != 0) {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rp.getContent()));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line);
}
origresponseText = sb.toString();
}
```